# How to perform a Sqlite query in android by using a search value in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have been following the new boston series for Android and i wanted to try something. So, i wanted to enter a name in a edit text and retrieve the relevant details from the sqlite database. My code shows error and i am unable to fix it. Can anyone please suggest me what could be my mistake?

Following is one of the method that is supposed to give me the item name by querying the Username in the edittext but it gives me error

```
public String getItemname(String l) throws SQLException{
        String[] columns = new String[]
                {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_INAME, KEY_ICODE, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_DATE, KEY_TNAME};
        Cursor c = ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,KEY_NAME + "=" + l,null,null,null,null);

        if(c!= null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String itemname = c.getString(2);
            return itemname;

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Note:- I don't get any specific error pointing at a particular line of code but it just shows that the "Unfortunately Program has crashed"

Comment: you had better add the error.

Comment: @burakKarasoy:- It doesnt show any specific error. Just shows that the program has closed unexpectedly.